# Webpack hot reload

Tags: javascript, webpack

Пытаюсь настроить webpack для работы hot reload со скриптами нет проблем, а вот стили не хотят автоматически перезагружаться. Я пишу изменяю что то в SCSS и Webpack dev server выдает мне

> [WDS] App hot update...
>   [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
>   [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (They would need a full reload!) [HMR]  - 596
>   [HMR] Nothing hot updated.
>   [HMR] App is up to date.

Весь код выложил здесь https://bitbucket.org/perevezenzev/reactstartkit (в ветке add-css) в чем моя проблема?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin — «No Hot Module Replacement»

Comment: Обидно. А есть ли что то похожего функционала и поддерживающее Hot Reload?

Comment: Я просто подключаю этот плагин только для окончательной сборки

Comment: А как вы тогда подключаете ваши CSS файлы к HTML ?